# Windows phone save form

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm developing some app for Windows phone 8.1, and I have this problem:
Have 1 form with some checkbox, radio buttons and some text fields. When I fill it up, and move to next form with:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(SOME_FORM));
```

and I have some things to do, and want to come back to 1st form, it's all cleared. How to remember what i fill up on 1st form, when i come back from 2nd?

And I add all controls programmatically, so I can't save it in static variable.
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first page set property NavigationCacheMode to Required
in XAML

```
NavigationCacheMode="Required"
```

or in code behind

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
```

But the question is: when do you add controls to page? if you add control in OnNavigatedTo you should check NavigationMode and don't reload page on back navigation

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
        {
//do nothing - filled controls already there
            return;
        }
        //add controls
    }
```

Comment: Hmmm... In one method i have code for create all controls, and i call that method below this:     this.InitializeComponent();      It's not on LoadForm and it's not on OnNavigatedTo. Maybe if i put there where you said it'll be better?